# JavaFX Scenebuilder fill listView from database

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I made a JavaFX Scenebuilder "Application" and I need to fill my listView with things from my database. The problem is that I don't know how and I don't know where to look.

Is there someone who can help me out?

Here is the code with my connection to the database. That's the only thing I have. And the scene builder "Sample.fxml" file of course.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        Connection Conn = null;

        try {
            Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hitdossier", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Verbonden met de database");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Verbinding met de database is mislukt.");
        }

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = Conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT naam FROM artiest");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }

        primaryStage.setTitle("Eindopdracht Java Periode 4");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 650));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

This is my Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class Controller {
   @FXML
   private ComboBox<String> cboWeek;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for the following code:

First define your listView and an observable list (assuming that you have a ListView in your fxml with the id "list"):

```
@FXML
ListView<String> list;

ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Then set the list view to the items list:

```
list.setItems(items);
```

in your while loop simply add the results to the items list:

```
items.add(rs.getString(1));
```

Comment: **Never** initialize a variable that is annotated `@FXML`.

Comment: Thanks @James_D, I edited the mistake. This occurred, because in my first answer I wanted to add the list via code :)

Comment: You should probably also make clear that this code should be in the controller...

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (code not tested):

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Eindopdracht Java Periode 4");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 650));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Controller.java (associated with a fxml that contains a ListView with id=list):

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
   @FXML
   private ListView<String> list;

   private ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       list.setItems(items);

       Connection Conn = null;

       try {
           Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hitdossier", "root", "");
           System.out.println("Verbonden met de database");
       } catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             System.out.println("Verbinding met de database is mislukt.");
       }

       Statement stmt = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       try {
           stmt = Conn.createStatement();
           rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT naam FROM artiest");

           while (rs.next()) {
               items.add(rs.getString(1));
               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {

       }

   }

}
```

By implementing the initialize method you could load the contents whenever the scene is shown.